# select multiple rows on nested condition in mysql database

Tags: mysql, rows, limits, levels

select multiple rows on nested condition and nested limit in mysql database

Actually i have one table like:

```
id  name   levels 
1   Red          1
2   Red Light    1
3   Green        2
4   Green Light  2
5   Blue         3
6   Blue Light   3
7   Blue Dark    3

I want fetch any rows according to levels with any limits Like: 
From Level-1 = 1 row
From Level-2 = 2 row
From Level-3 = 2 row
 total rows are 5 according to levels.
Any one know about single query is possible?
 or
three foreach loop will be implement?
```

Comment: any body can resolve this problem?